# Es correcto preguntar "donde es"?

Tags: cópulas, preguntas

Recentemente, he escuchado hablantes nativos de español usando ser en situaciones donde yo usaría estar.
La primera vez - un amigo Dominicano y yo estabamos planeando juntarnos en un concierto. Le pregunté, "dónde está el concierto?" Me correctó - "dónde es."
La segunda era parecida. Un amigo Colombiano y yo estabamos discutiendo planes para mas tarde en la noche. Le dije, "Vamos a otro sitio. Es un club con una banda de salsa y comida." Me preguntó, "dónde es?".

Estos usos son correctos? Hay situaciones cuando tiene sentido usar la palabra ser cuando hablas de ubicacion? Tiene que ver con asistir en algo no tangible como concierto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En castellano se pregunta:
¿Dónde está? cuando la ubicación puede ir cambiando
¿Dónde es? cuando la ubicación no cambia.

En el caso del concierto, lo que sucede es que el concierto no se mueve (la banda puede dar más conciertos en otros lugares, pero el concierto en sí es el acto de ese día), y ese acto sucede en un lugar específico.

- ¿Dónde está hoy la banda?
- Está dando un concierto.
- ¿Y el concierto donde es?
- El concierto es en Buenos Aires.

Sin embargo puede que ocurran casos que sean irregulares, por ejemplo:
Si te preguntan por la ubicación de lugares (ciudades, países, etc) te preguntarán:

- ¿Dónde está Madrid?
- Madrid está en España.
  Y esto en general se entiende bien, aunque podría ser gramaticalmente incorrecto.
  También te preguntarán:
- ¿Madrid en dónde es?
- Madrid es en España.
  Esta construcción se usará menos frecuentemente, pero es correcta.

La regla general, es la que está descrita arriba. Ten en cuenta que esto también puede variar dependiendo de la zona en la que te encuentres (Algunas regiones hispanohablantes, han modificado ciertas normas gramaticales debido a la interferencia con otros lenguages cercanos).